# How come this rails query works locally but fails on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-migrations

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@featured_topics = Topic.find_all_by_featured(true)
```

It works fine locally, but when I upload my site to Heroku, it fails, and I get a NoMethodError. "Featured" is a new column, but I uploaded the necessary files and ran rake db:migrate on Heroku. Why doesn't it work on Heroku? The rest of the site still works.

Comment: Did you migrate the correct environment?

Comment: @meagar, I just ran heroku rake db:migrate, did I need to be more specific?

Comment: Did you restart your app after migrating: `heroku restart`?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm, that fixed it, thanks. It worked locally without any restart, so I didn't realize.

Comment: It sounds like the migration wasn't checked in or the db:migrate was not successful. Run: heroku run rails console and check the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is a subtle one that only occurs when your app is in production mode (i.e. when `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` or `ENV['RACK_ENV']` = `production`), which is the default configuration on Heroku.

When a Rails app is in `production` mode it doesn't reload class definitions on every request (as it does in `development` mode which you are running locally). Part of a model's class definition are the attributes which are fetched from database columns at the time the class is loaded. So, if you load a class in `production`, then change the database, the loaded classes won't know the db has changed and you'll get the `NoMethodError` for the new columns.

To understand how this happened in your case on Heroku consider the following sequence:

1. App deployed w/ new `Topic.find_all_by_featured` column reference

   1. App restarted automatically by Heroku
   2. A request comes into your app which causes classes to be loaded in memory from current state of the database (w/o the `featured` column)
2. You run `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`

   1. Your db on Heroku is update with new `featured` column
   2. Model classes already in memory in a Heroku dyno are *not* reloaded. They still don't know about the new column.
3. You hit your app. Rails throws an error because a field referenced in your code isn't in its list of database columns (loaded at step #1).

The correct sequence to avoid such a situation is to turn on maintenance mode for both the deploy and db migration:

```
$ heroku maintenance:on
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ heroku maintenance:off
```

Turning maintenance on while you deploy and migrate ensures that no requests are handled by your app and that no classes (with incorrect column lists) are loaded. Only after the db is in the proper state do you allow requests.